# Matrices in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, applications, bilinear-form

Let: $ u: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by: $$ u(x,y)=(x+2y, 2x-y, 2x+ 3y)$$
Give the matrix $M[u]$ in the canonical base of its definition space.

This question might seem sort of stupid, but it was part of an exam we had a few days back, and we never had $u$ under this form to work with before. I thought of it this way:
$u_1 = x+2y$;
$u_2= 2x - y$;
$u_3= 2x + 3y$;

And so I placed each $u_i$ in its respective column in the matrix (the coefficients that is). But according to the answer sheet that the professor posted, the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ are the ones placed column-wise. Any thoughts or explanations as to why they should be written like that?

Comment: So your matrix of transformation is $$u(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2 \\ 
 2& -1\\ 
 2&3 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 

\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Because what we need is to write $M(u)(x,y)^T=(x+2y,2x-y,2x+3y )^T$ and we need the matrix abd vector dimensions to agree, so $M(u)$ mist be a $3\times 2$ matrix, so we place the coefficients as the rows of $M$